# Can you create a secondary index on a repeated field in Riak?

Tags: riak

Consider a JSON object such as:

```
{
  name: 'ben',
  employer: 'The Sherwin-Williams Company',
  emails: ['ben@gmail.com', 'ben@sherwin-williams.com']
}
```

In MongoDB you can index the emails field such that you can find any object with 'ben@gmail.com' as an email. Is this possible in Riak? I couldn't tell from reading [the docs](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/querying/Secondary-Indexes/).

Comment: What client library are you planning on using?

Comment: Do some client libraries allow it and not others? If so, then I would choose one that allows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can, but you have to manually enter the index entries.

Here's an example in Ruby:

```
require 'riak'

client = Riak::Client.new(:protocol => "pbc", :host => "127.0.0.1", :pb_port => 10047, :http_port => 10048)

ben = client['people'].get_or_new('ben')

ben.data = { :name => "ben", 
             :employer => "The Sherwin-Williams Company",
             :emails => ['ben@gmail.com', 'ben@sherwin-williams.com'] }

ben.indexes['email_bin'] << "ben@gmail.com"
ben.indexes['email_bin'] << "ben@sherwin-williams.com"

ben.store
```

Now you can look it up via the ruby library, or through your web browser at `http://127.0.0.1:10018/buckets/people/index/email_bin/ben@gmail.com`

On my system this returns:
`{"keys":["ben"]}`

I know the Java and the Ruby Riak libraries support adding/editing index entries, I will have to check on the others and get back to you though.